# Clojure. Vectors and Lists. cons and peek

Tags: clojure

Clojure noob here. Playing around with lists and vectors.

```
> (peek [1 2 3 4])
4
> (peek '(1 2 3 4))
1
```

Works as promised. Just like this does.

```
> (cons 1 [2 3 4])
(1 2 3 4)
> (cons 1 '(2 3 4))
(1 2 3 4)
```

I randomly tried to use *peek* on the result of *cons*:

```
> (peek (cons 1 [2 3 4]))
ClassCastException clojure.lang.Cons cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IPersistentStack  clojure.lang.RT.peek (RT.java:724)
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45525668/1562315):

> Playing around I found that `cons` doesn't plainly return a sequence
>   like it claims.

Yes it does: `cons` always returns a sequence:

- `cons` returns a `clojure.lang.Cons`,
- which extends `ASeq`,
- which implements `ISeq`.

> My guess is that it returns a lazy sequence ...

A `Cons` is never a lazy sequence. It may be wrapped in a lazy sequence. Its tail may be a lazy sequence. But it, itself, is not a lazy sequence.

---

Concerning your question:

`peek` doesn't work on `cons` because `peek` requires an `IPersistentStack`: an interface that `Cons` doesn't implement. So far as I can see, it well could.

Answer (score 2):

Playing around I found that cons doesn't plainly return a sequence like it claims. My guess is that it returns a lazy sequence because:

```
> (type (cons 1 [2 3 4]))
clojure.lang.Cons
```

I found this way of realizing it

```
> (peek (into [] (cons 1 '(2 3 4))))
4
```

Comment: Right, but I think more important is that `peek` and `cons` are related to different abstractions, so you shouldn’t mix them like this. `peek` is for treating *persistent collections* as ‘stacks’, `cons` is for constructing *seqs*. See `first` and `last`.

Comment: See also `conj` for adding items to collections (including to stacks).